# Mixed JS and TS - Eslint no longer throwing error for js and jsx files

Tags: reactjs, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have my `.eslintrc.js` as such:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
  parserOptions: {
    requireConfigFile: false,
    babelOptions: {
      presets: ["@babel/preset-react"],
    },
  },
  plugins: ["react", "react-hooks"],
  rules: {
    "no-console": "off",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@no-restricted-globals": "off",
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
      env: { browser: true, es6: true, node: true },
      extends: [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
      ],
      parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
      parserOptions: {
        ecmaFeatures: { jsx: true },
        ecmaVersion: 2018,
        sourceType: "module",
        project: "./tsconfig.json",
      },
      plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
      rules: {
        "no-console": "off",
        "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "off",
        "no-unused-vars": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "warn",
        "@no-restricted-globals": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": "off",
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

This works fine where it throws error finely for `ts` and `tsx` files. But after setting this up, my eslint doesn't throw any error for `js` and `jsx` files anymore. How can I set it up so that it throws error for both accordingly and properly?

Comment: Curiosity: why did you manually add `"plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended"`? It's included by `"plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"`. See https://typescript-eslint.io/users/configs#eslint-recommended.

Comment: @Josh Hmm it's been awhile, but I think I copied somewhere regarding this as it wasn't working for my TS

Comment: I'd suggest going through the typescript-eslint _getting started_ docs: https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started/legacy-eslint-setup (since you're on the legacy ESLint config format still). They explain how to lint js(x) + ts(x) projects. Unless you're doing some funky unusual things, `@babel/eslint-parser` isn't generally necessary anymore. You can use typescript-eslint for everything.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to use the same parser for both my Javascript and Typescript files. My configuration now looks something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  ignorePatterns: ["node_modules", "dist", "build", ".eslintrc.js"],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ["**/*.js", "**/*.jsx", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
      env: { browser: true, es6: true, node: true },
      extends: ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],
      parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
      parserOptions: {
        ecmaFeatures: { jsx: true },
        ecmaVersion: 2018,
        sourceType: "module",
        project: "./tsconfig.json",
      },
      plugins: ["@typescript-eslint", "react", "react-hooks"],
      rules: {
        // TURNED OFF
        "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "off",
        "no-console": "off",
        "@no-restricted-globals": "off",
        "no-case-declarations": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "off",

        // WARNING
        "no-unused-vars": "warn",
        "no-empty": "warn",
        "no-dupe-else-if": "warn",
        "no-unsafe-optional-chaining": "warn",
        "no-useless-escape": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias": "warn",
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I'm not entirely sure this is the best practice but this works for now. If anyone has any input on this, feel free to leave a comment so I can improve my `.eslintrc.js`